# Cannot Read Property Style Of Null

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, nav

I've been getting this error when trying to hide my mobile nav when a link is clicked.  It seems like a pretty simple issue, and I've looked through some similar questions but I can't seem to figure it out.

My HTML

```
<div id=mobilenav class=mobilenav onclick="HideNav();">
    <nav id=nav>
    </nav>
</div>
```

`mobilenav` is hidden on default, and when the screen shrinks I show it.

The CSS

```
.mobilenav {
    display:none
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .mobilenav {
        display: block;   
    }
}
```

When a link in `mobilenav` is clicked I run this JavaScript function:

```
function HideNav () {

    var nav = document.getElementById(nav);

    nav.style.display='none';
}
```

But the console is giving me the "Cannot read property style of null" error.  I'm not sure how `nav` is null.

Comment: Although I'm now just realizing that won't work anyways, because the chid elements are going to be hidden anyways...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should be

```
var nav = document.getElementById("nav");
```

You have to pass a **string** to the routine. Your code would not have resulted in an error because the variable was declared in your function, but it would have had no value.

Answer (score 2):

Yup the Pointy answer is correct.
It worked for me.

```
<div id="mobilenav" class="mobilenav" onclick="HideNav();">
 <nav id="nav"> 
   Iam inside the nav id.
 </nav>
   Iam outside the nav id.
</div>

<style type="text/css">
.mobilenav {
display:none; /* Hides the Content */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
.mobilenav {
    display: block;   /* Displays the content */
  }
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function HideNav () {
     var nav = document.getElementById("nav");
       nav.style.display='none';
    }
</script>
```